# Let $f(z) =: \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} (2n+1)z^n$. Find the power series representation of $g(z):=f(z)-zf(z)$ and show $g(z) = \frac {1+z} {1-z}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $f(z) =: \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} (2n+1)z^n$.

I've verified that this power series has convergence radius $R=1$ be considering $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |a_n|/|a_{n+1}|$

However I must find the power series representation of $g(z):=f(z)-zf(z)$ and show $g(z) =  \frac {1+z} {1-z}$ for $|z|<1$.

I know since $f(z)$ converges $zf(z)$ also converges, so their difference convergence. $g(z)$ is thus well-defined with domain $|z|<1$ and $g(z) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} (2n+1)z^n -(2n+1)z^{n+1}$.

But this doesn't look like a power series ? How can I make it into a power series ?

Comment: Write out the first few terms to see that $g(z) = 1 + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} z^{n} = 1 + 2 \frac{z}{1-z} = \frac{1+z}{1-z}$.

Comment: why does the sum equal $z/(1-z)$ and not $1/(1-z)$ ? its a geometric sum ?

Comment: The sum starts from $k=1$ and not $k=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(2n+1)z^{n+1}=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(\color{red}{2n-1})z^{n}
$$
hence
$$g(z) = 1+\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (2n+1-(\color{red}{2n-1}))z^n=1+\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\ldots$$

Comment: Thank you @Did, it was very useful.